# Installing Windows without superdrive or USB

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, optical-drive

I'm trying to intall Windows 7 on my Mid 2009 Macbook Pro, however I'm running into A LOT of trouble.

My superdrive have been broken for years and I can't boot from a bootable USB. (I created one in Virtual Box using the Windows 7 USB/DVD Tool)

I then followed this tutorial on how to start the installation from within VMWare Fusion (http://www.andrewsavory.com/blog/2011/2156#), which seemed to work at first, but once I rebooted and selected the Windows Partition I got an error saying that windows could not be installed due to "recent software or hardware changes".
I had selected the x86 version, so I figured I might as well try the x64 version and see if that makes a difference.

So I removed my bootcamp partition, created it again, went into VMWare after doing the same process as before, now I simply get a message saying "No operating system found".

I'm wondering with my options are to actually install Windows without a superdrive or a bootable USB.
Can I just copy the installation files to the bootcamp partition and "make it start"?

Comment: The answer to  your last question, I strongly recommend using Bootcamp's way of doing things.

Comment: @ShaneHsu Sure, I would love too, but it seems impossible, I followed all tutorials on how to create a bootable USB with bootcamp but the option just won't show up

Answer (score 1):

Try using [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/download/en/) in creating your bootable USB.

I also ran into problems when creating a Bootcamp partition. I also don't have access to a SuperDrive when I created a Windows partition.

First, use WinToFlash on your Windows 7 iso. Please use at least a 4GB USB drive and make sure that you don't have any important files in that drive as WinToFlash will delete all files when creating the bootable USB. After creating the bootable USB, go ahead and create a Bootcamp partition in your Mac drive using this [tutorial](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=2672). Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that I can't boot from a USB, even though I created multiple bootable ones

Comment: Have you tried WinToFlash in creating your bootable USB? I had the same problem when I used the Windows 7 USB/DVD Tool in creating the bootable disk.

Comment: Tried it yesterday, but gave me an error saying `windows could not collect information for [OSImage] since the specified image file [install.wim] does not exist`, but at least it booted from the USB now

Comment: Where did you obtained your copy of Windows 7? Have you tried using it before just to be sure that it is a working and complete copy.

Comment: I bought it online a few months ago, I used the same copy to install it on my VirtualBox before, I'm trying it again now, maybe something went wrong in the process.

Comment: I see what happened, for some reason WinToFlash never copies the install.wim file, even though there is enough space left, it doesn't want to copy that specific file

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work but have you formatted your drive to FAT32 before using WinToFlash?

Comment: I did, I've been trying for the past 4 days now, but no luck, I got to the point where the installation was about to start, but then i got a message saying it failed to load install.wim. I guess it might just be easier to run VirtualBox and deal with the slow performance.